# How to get discriminated union behavior with overloading

Tags: typescript

I have function overloading

```
function MyFunc(values: IFirst, type: MyEnum.FIRST): number
function MyFunc(values: ISecond, type: MyEnum.SECOND): number
function MyFunc(values: (IFirst | ISecond), type: (MyEnum.FIRST | MyEnum.SECOND)): number {
  if(type === MyEnum.FIRST) {
    values.
  }
  ...
}
```

Why my values inside `if` statement is conjunction of `IFirst` and `ISecond` ?

How to get [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) behavior here? Without adding `type` string to interfaces, but with type argument.

I want my values to be `IFirst` in `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap parameters in object, so they can be discriminated:

```
enum MyEnum {
    FIRST,
    SECOND
}

interface IFirst {
    first: number;
}

interface ISecond {
    second: number;
}

function MyFunc(param: { value: IFirst, type: MyEnum.FIRST }): number
function MyFunc(param: { value: ISecond, type: MyEnum.SECOND }): number
function MyFunc(param: { value: IFirst, type: MyEnum.FIRST } | { value: ISecond, type: MyEnum.SECOND }): number {
    if (param.type === MyEnum.FIRST) {
        return param.value.first;
    } else {
        return param.value.second;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables (or parameters) in this case never narrow one another, they can only narrow themselves.

You can get the discriminated union behavior with a tuple, and you can use tuples in rest parameters to spread the tuple to the parameters. The biggest disadvantage of this is you will have to access the tuple items with numbers.

```
function MyFunc(values: IFirst, type: MyEnum.FIRST): number
function MyFunc(values: ISecond, type: MyEnum.SECOND): number
function MyFunc(...params: [IFirst, MyEnum.FIRST] | [ISecond, MyEnum.SECOND]): number {
  if(params[1] === MyEnum.FIRST) {
      return params[0].first;
  } else {
      return params[0].second;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3lAYgSQEoGUAqANFLggMIDyAcgCJQC+AsAFACWIALsAE4BmAhgGNgUTOlbcAzhyhpeE6QC4oyAEY8GLdlz5CRmXMEEB7EABNZUSUdNnlajU2YsWvMCEEdWp2HHTvBAAoAN34AGzBgSWUxBQ5iDjgAB2BleCRIADosPHwASntIdW5XAK8feH8PEPDI6NFDE3ME5NTfDIhM0kpaApUinlKPcpBfKqDMyaT+bn4IeoBtWKl49uRsnAIAXSgAHyglxttidPXu6hotvoduWRYoKFZeQOnZ+YWARh2AXl+1rJyBDyd2YDzBUG4wA4YG4o1ec0kCwADFtMvIVgBue4MKDAMLWEHgh6Q6GwqDw94ozLWJpmLGgzTMJwsIA)